# Can every average of twin prime pairs be expressed by the sum of two smaller averages

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's call $A$ the group of Averages of twin prime pairs (the composite between two twin primes as in [OEIS A014574](https://oeis.org/A014574)).
I noticed that for small numbers in $A$ they can be expressed as the sum of two other numbers in $A$. I wonder if it is true for any such numbers in $A$ (***of course excluding 4 , 6***), meaning:

**$A \setminus \{4,6\}$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Image}(f)$** with $f(x,y) : A \times A \to B$ defined as
$$
 \qquad (x,y)\overset{f}{\mapsto}\!(x + y)
$$

how should I try to prove / find counter example to this problem?

thx for help.

Comment: These averages are always multiples of six (except, of course, the average of three and five). Dividing by six gives https://oeis.org/A002822 so the question can be rephrased as whether every (sufficiently large) number in 002822 is a sum of two numbers in 002822. But then I suppose one could ask whether every sufficiently large integer is a sum of two numbers in 002822.

Comment: thx for editing my qeustion so it will be more readable.

Comment: your second suggestion is harder question then whether every sufficiently large integer is the sum of two twin primes. as for the first, thats nice way to rephrase the question, but im more curious of what intresting things can we learn about it if its true.

Comment: I tested up to $n=1,000,000$ where $6 n=6,000,000$ and found no counter examples.

Comment: The number of ways of expressing an element in $A$ as the sum of two other elements in $A$ seems to match [OEIS Entry A134143](https://oeis.org/A134143).